# ASP.NET AJAX UpdateProgress in User Control for UpdatePanel in parent page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, user-controls, webforms, updatepanel

I'm working on an ASP.NET web forms application. In my Page I have an `UpdatePanel` and a user control with an `UpdateProgress` and a bunch of buttons. When the user clicks one of the buttons, I'd like to perform an asynchronous postback and show the `UpdateProgress`.

Can anyone help me with **making the postback asynchronous** (looks like it works) as well as **making the `UpdateProgress` appear** (doesn't work yet)?

Usually, this can be done pretty easily by defining an `UpdateTrigger` in the page markup. Inside the user control it isn't. I exposed a public property `AssociatedUpdatePanelID`, to have the `UpdatePanel`'s ID inside the control.

The `UpdateProgress` is defined as follows:

```
<asp:UpdateProgress AssociatedUpdatePanelID='<%# AssociatedUpdatePanelID %>' />
```

That's what I tried in my control's `Page_Load`, but none of the approaches works (postback is performed, but `UpdateProgress` does not appear):

```
updatePanel.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
{
    ControlID = this.ID,
    EventName = "RequestOptimize"
});

var scriptMgr = ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
scriptMgr.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(optimizeButtonJobs);
scriptMgr.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);
```

Comment: Why dont you put an UpdatePanel inside your UserControl?

Comment: I use the user control together with a `GridView` in an `UpdatePanel` on multiple pages. The user control is always the same - the `GridView` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just register your user control on the page as an async postback trigger. No more magic required. The reason it didn't work for me was a PostBackUrl property that was (accidentially) set on the button.

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myCustomControl" />
```